# I can't set up auth0 with nestjs

Tags: jwt, nestjs, authorization, passport.js, auth0

I followed Auth0's NestJs tutorial: https://auth0.com/blog/developing-a-secure-api-with-nestjs-adding-authorization/

so far so good, I have public routes that work fine, but when testing a protected route with AuthGuard, I have a 401.
I've obviously passed the bearer token obtained via the POST request https://xxx.us.auth0.com/oauth/token

but nothing works...

Could someone please help me?

Here is my module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }), UsersModule],
  providers: [JwtStrategy, AuthService, UsersService],
  exports: [PassportModule],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

and the controller:

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  @Get('/protected')
  getprotected(): string {
    return 'protected data';
  }
```

and the jwtstrtagey:

```
dotenv.config();

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      secretOrKeyProvider: passportJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: `${process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER_URL}.well-known/jwks.json`,
      }),

      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
      issuer: `${process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER_URL}`,
      algorithms: ['RS256'],
    });
  }

  validate(payload: unknown): unknown {
    return payload;
  }
```

I spent the whole afternoon there ...